# perl floor function giving error undefined subroutine &main::floor

Tags: perl

I'm new to perl and following piece of code is not working and getting the following error. I tried googling but coundn't get any solution.

```
$halfSize = floor($halfSize);
```

Undefined subroutine &main::floor called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`floor` is spelt `int` in perl:

```
my $num = 22.8;
my $floor = int($num);
say $floor;
# => 22
```

... but be aware - as Borodin pointed out in the comments - that `int` rounds towards 0 which will give a different results for negative numbers.

Alternatively, you can use the POSIX version;

```
use POSIX qw/floor/;

my $num = 22.6;
my $floor = floor($num);
say $floor;
# => 22
```

Comment: `floor` is different from `int` for negative numbers. `int` rounds towards zero while `floor` rounds towards −∞

Answer (score 6):

`floor` isn't a built-in operator in Perl

You can use the [`Math::Utils`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Math::Utils) module like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Math::Utils 'floor';

say floor(1.5);
say floor(-1.5);
```

#### output

```
1
-2
```

You may need to install `Math::Utils` as it is not a core module. The [`POSIX`](https://metacpan.org/pod/POSIX) module also has a `floor` function and should be installed as part of Perl so you can use that by writing `use POSIX 'floor'` instead. But it's a huge module that contains a lot of functions that you won't need. On my system, `Math::Utils` occupies 1MB compared to 1.7MB for POSIX. The choice is yours

Alternatively you can write your own `floor` subroutine in terms of the built-in operator `int`

```
sub floor {
    my ($n) = @_;
    my $int_n = int($n);
    $n < 0 && $int_n != $n ? $int_n - 1: $int_n;
}
```